# некорректный URI путь к файлу в папке raw?

Tags: java, android, uri

В общем в папке raw лежат записи под названиями а1, а2, а3 и тд.
Хочу задать к ним путь вручную, без использования методов.
String переменная **recordNumber** генерируется рандомно и содержит в себе порядковый номер записи.
Через переменную **uriPath** хочу получить uri путь до этого аудиофайла.
При проигрывании файла - программа вылетает. Android Studio ошибок не видит и причину вылета программы тоже не сообщает.

Имеет ли вообще место такая запись?
Не пойму, то ли я просто путь указываю некорректно, то ли сама форма записи неверная и нужно по-другому.

```
String uriPath =  "src/main/res/raw/a"+ recordNumber;

Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);

recordToListen = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);

soundButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View view) {

soundPlayButton(recordToListen);
```

Comment: какова цель всего этого?

Comment: На активити у нас вызывается рандомное слово. Нажав на него, пользователь переходит в другое активити там к этому слову даны пояснения и должно проиграться аудио. 

Например. генерируется слово Кошка.  Пользователь нажимает на слово кошка, переходит на следущую активити, там описание кошки и кнопка, нажав на которую пользователь получит звук мяу, который привязан должен быть именно к слову кошка.
Если сгенерируется другое слово, то будет другой звук, соответственно.

привязка осуществляется через переменную recordNumber.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#OriginalFiles

Comment: Там получается в итоге, что мы должны иметь 
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("a1.mp3"); 
В кавычки берется именно название файла, которое лежит в ассетах. 

Вопрос меняется, но суть остается: можно ли использовать переменную. в этом случае? Например вместо, a1.mp3 поставить  переменную типа String recordNumber, которая будет генерироваться в зависимости от результата на предыдущей активити.

Comment: Ну так а что мешает-то? Там строка и тут строка.

Comment: Проблема в постановке переменной в методе, который просит не переменную, а именно название 
 файла внутри кавычек. 
openFd("переменная")

Comment: Проблема в вашем непонимании синтаксиса. Метод просит строку, а не "название файла внутри кавычек".

Comment: Вы правы. Непонимание есть. В любом случае, вставляю строковую переменную внутрь метода - он не воспринимает. Воспринимает, только название файла из ассета в кавычках.

String recordName  = "a1.mp3";
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(recordName);    вот так не воспроизводит. просто тишина.

String recordName  = "\"a1.mp3\"";
AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd(recordName);     вот так тоже тишина.


AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = getAssets().openFd("a1.mp3");    а вот так воспроизводит. но так не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это - `src/main/res/raw/a` - есть только на вашем компьютере. В самом андроиде/эмуляторе такого пути нет.

Comment: Подскажите, а как тогда задать правильно, чтобы было для эмулятора?